# ¿Por qué "¿Puede alguien ayudarme?” no es realmente una pregunta?

Tags: discusión, preguntas

Para un usuario, su pregunta parece perfectamente correcta. Ha explicado el contexto de su proyecto, hay una lista detallada de qué quiere conseguir y ha mostrado qué ha intentado/su trabajo hasta ahora.

El problema es claro y necesita ayuda para conseguir esas tareas.

¿Por qué preguntas así reciben votos negativos y de cierre? En los comentarios, la gente dice que no han preguntado nada cuando claramente sí lo han hecho.

---

*Tanto la pregunta como la respuesta son una traducción más o menos libre de [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/579895)*

Comment: Porque la respuesta es: "Si". Y eso es filosofía, no programación.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Stack Overflow en Español es un sitio de  *Preguntas y Respuestas*. Puedes pensar que has realizado una pregunta razonable y contestable, pero en realidad no lo has hecho..

Primero, pongámonos en situación. Este sitio intenta crear un repositorio de conocimiento de soluciones a problemas de programación. Eso significa que la característica principal de una buena pregunta es **que es probable que pueda ser útil/buscada por alguna otra persona**.

"Podéis ayudarme a implementar una aplicación que haga X?" no consigue eso. Es muy probable que *nadie* vuelva nunca a intentar hacer exactamente lo mismo que tu exactamente de la misma manera. Preguntas como: "¿Cómo puedo convertir una cadena a un número?" *si* son buscadas muy a menudo.

Segundo, sólo por ver donde nos lleva, digamos que no nos importa si la pregunta es útil para alguien mas, que los usuarios estamos aquí sólo para *ti* (no, no lo estamos). Aún asi es **imposible contestar**.

Imagina como sería la respuesta. Esencialmente tendría que ser absolutamente todo el código necesario. Podemos entender que tu solo quieras "ayuda", pero con la pregunta que has hecho, *no podemos dártela*. Compáralo con la pregunta de arriba (*"¿Cómo puedo convertir una cadena a un número?"*), que tiene una respuesta concreta y clara (o incluso varias respuestas).

En resumen, **ayúdanos a ayudarte**. Cuando hagas una pregunta, **asegúrate de realmente  hacer una pregunta**. Preguntas susceptibles de ser contestadas no tratan sobre cómo implementar una característica genérica (*¿cómo puedo implementar un editor de textos?*), preguntan como realizar una tarea de programación (*¿cómo poner en negrita un texto?*,*¿cómo imprimo un bloque de texto?*... ).

Hay un *truco*, y es que hacer una buena pregunta hará casi siempre que debas conocer lo suficiente para *saber que es lo que no sabes*. Si no estás en ese punto todavía, comienza por dividir tu problema en tantos pequeños pasos como sea necesario, y haz preguntas sobre los pasos que no entiendas.

En resumen:

- Haz una pregunta clara, concreta y de utilidad general que sea apropiada para programadores y entusiastas del desarrollo y uso de software. No hagas preguntas que solo podrían interesarte a ti, que son muy amplias, que no contengan todos los detalles necesarios para poder responderla, que requieran aclaraciones o que no traten sobre desarrollo o uso de software.
- Si no tienes clara cual sería esa pregunta de programación, al menos divide tu problema en cuantas mas partes básicas mejor, y aún así siempre que seán sobre programación y no sobre la característica que intentas implementar
- Haz una sola pregunta por publicación, así son mucho mas útiles.
- Espera a las reacciones que obtengas y *piensa* sobre ellas *antes* de realizar tu siguiente pregunta. Puede hacer que quede obsoleta o que cambie radicalmente.

La buena noticia es que *estás intentando aprender*. Así que trabaja en tu pregunta, edítala para convertirla en algo susceptible de ser respondido, o al menos asegúrate de que tu próxima pregunta sea una buena pregunta. ¡Estaremos encantados de ayudarte!

Comment: ¿Qué significa _"Haz una pregunta sobre programación, no cómo implementar algo"_? No me queda claro.

Comment: @toledano Si,la traducción de eso me quedo poco clara. En ingles se habla de _implement a feature_, si alguien tiene una traducción mejor puede con total confianza editarlo

Comment: No veo por qué no se va a poder preguntar cómo implementar algo. Es especialmente hiriente que se diga eso en una comunidad en que se pide muy frecuentemente que las preguntas contengan código.

Comment: Ahora tengo duda en que es eso de _"tarea de programación"_ que parece lo opuesto a _"implementar una característica"_. Y no, no es un problema con la traducción, sino con la respuesta en sí. __¿Por qué no puedo pedir ayuda para hacer algo?__ ¿Es un problema de redacción con el título solamente? Ejemplo: _"Me pueden ayuda a obtener un nuevo token JWT con refresh"_ según esto no es una pregunta; pero si pregunto: _"Cómo puedo obtener un nuevo token JWT usando refresh"_, entonces si es una pregunta. O.o No me lo creo.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos creo que lo que dices puede ser un error de traducción mio o de interpretación. Lo que yo entiendo es que se refiere a preguntas muy genéricas de implementación, se me ocurre por ejemplo: "Como puedo implementar un chat en mi aplicación web?"  o "como puedo implementar un sistema de punto de venta en C#?" De todas maneras, como digo esto es una simple traducción de un post de meta en inglés. No está escrito en piedra y os invito a modificarlo para aclarar cualquier punto o para que el consenso sea lo mas amplio posible.

Comment: @toledano yo pensé que estaba muy clara tanto la pregunta como la respuesta pero veo que no es así. En ningún caso se dice que no puedas pedir ayuda para hacer algo. La base de este post son las preguntas en las que se pide "puede alguien ayudarme" cuando realmente no se ha hecho una pregunta concreta. Un ejemplo es una pregunta en la que el cuerpo es sólamente un código y la frase "¿puede alguien ayudarme?" o alguna variante. La pregunta no debe ser esa (Stack Overflow en español se trata de eso, de ayudar, así que va implicita), sino una pregunta concreta sobre que se quiere implementar.

Comment: Si lo que se busca son títulos de mejor calidad de cara a posicionar resultados en los buscadores, me parece una estupenda idea "orientar" a los usuarios para que se prioricen títulos del tipo "Cómo hacer *x*" sobre los del tipo "Necesito ayuda con *x*". No en vano, parece ser la dirección tomada por nuestra comunidad hermana mayor [so], a la que considero un espejo en el que mirarnos.

Comment: Jose Antonio y toledano, he editado la respuesta para intentar aclararla algo. De todas maneras, espero vuestras sugerencias: es cuestión de editarla para ajustarla mas al sitio o directamente estáis en contra de la pregunta/respuesta y 
pensais que debería ser eliminada? De momento y mientras está en disputa, la he retirado del FAQ

Comment: @Pikoh he editado la respuesta para eliminar la (desde mi punto de vista) innecesaria confrontación entre programación e implementación

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos me parece excelente tu edición. Queda mucho mas claro el concepto que se trataba de explicar. Gracias por tu aportación