# Necesito ayuda para encontrar **algo** relacionado con programación ¿puedo pedir ayuda aquí?

Tags: soporte, temática, propuesta-de-faq

Busco y busco y no encuentro **algo** que podría ser:

- Un fragmento de código (snippet)
- Una librería
- Un manual de un lenguaje
- Un libro sobre programación
- Una comunidad de programadores diferente a Stack Overflow en español
- Una API
- Un proyecto de código abierto
- La página de soporte al cliente de mi compañía favorita
- ... (cualquier cosa fuera del alcance del sitio definido [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

¿Qué hago?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Si cuentas con* **al menos 20 puntos** de reputación:

- pregunta en el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol). Con un poco de suerte encontrarás a alguien que podría ayudarte a encontrar lo que estás buscando.

*Si **aún no*** cuentas con la reputación requerida:

<sup>o cuentas con la reputación requerida pero no has obtenido respuesta o quieres otra</sup>

- *revisa* la [ayuda de Google](http://support.google.com/websearch) y si aún así necesitas ayuda sobre cómo buscar pasa por el [foro de ayuda de Búsqueda Web de Google](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/websearch-es)

  > Considera que lo que estás buscando podría no estar indexado por Google y bien que tal vez no esté accesible de forma abierta por lo que tal vez sea buena idea que tu mismo intentes resolver tu problema y si al hacer esto te encuentras con algo que preguntar que corresponda a la temática Stack Overflow en español por favor regresa y pregúntalo.
- revisa la lista de blogs de la comunidad -> [Vamos difundiendo nuestros blogs entre la hermandad de SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1203/65). Tal vez ahí encuentres un blog que trate el tema que estás buscando u ofrezca formas de ayudar en estos casos.

Preguntas relacionadas

- [¿Es correcto preguntar por un libro?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1786/65)
- [¿Por qué "¿Puede alguien ayudarme?” no es realmente una pregunta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2845/65)
- [¿Por qué no somos soporte al cliente de [tu compañía favorita]?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2525/65)