# ¿Cómo hacer preguntas sin código o que no son directamente de programación?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, temática, votos, pregunta-específica

¿Por qué preguntas como [¿Cómo consigo URL de política de privacidad en una página de Facebook?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/190827/como-consigo-url-de-politica-de-privacidad-en-una-pagina-de-facebook) son mal recibidas en la comunidad? Yo di un voto positivo pero antes de eso la pregunta tenía -1.

Y he visto otras preguntas con dudas concretas pero que al no tener relación directa con programación son votadas negativamente.

Lo que infiero es que son preguntas sin código o que no son directamente de programación, pero simplemente este tipo de dudas ¿no tienen cabida en Stack Overflow?

Es decir, esta pregunta por lo menos se entiende tan así que pude responderla.

¿Dónde o cómo se deben hacer estas preguntas? o ¿no se pueden hacer preguntas así en Stack Overflow?

Comment: mal recibida? según veo fue contestada de una manera explicativa por alguien de la comunidad.

Comment: @aloMalbarez de hecho el propio Emiliano fue quien la respondió y me uno a la duda, según veo no tiene votos negativos ni votos de cierre; entonces por que dices que no es bien recibida?

Comment: Porque antes de que yo la respondiera tenía -1 yo di el punto positivo

Comment: @EmilianoPamont al abrir una cuenta ya eres parte de la comunidad, recibiste bien la pregunta y la respondiste sin comentarios tóxicos del tipo RTFM. Los votos son siempre subjetivos.

Comment: Pero la cuestión es ¿Por qué las preguntas similares a estas no son bien recibidas y no sólo esta en particular? otras preguntas similares que no incluyen algún tipo de código, o incluso no se refieren a código son votadas negativas

Comment: @EmilianoPamont por que posiblemente esten fuera de los lineamientos que marca el centro de ayuda mira https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask del mismo modo en este enlace puedes ver sobre que temas se puede preguntar https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Como comentario aparte yo te sugiero no poner saludos o bienvenidas en las respuestas, recuerda que esta le puede servir a mas de una persona no solo al autor de la pregunta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Antes que nada, bienvenido a Meta.

Una aclaración sobre los saludos. Meta es un poco diferente al sitio principal, aquí se permiten las dicusiones mientras que allá no y acá se es un poco más laxo con las reglas como la inclusión de saludos, despidas y otras convensiones sociales.

Un único voto no debería ser considerado indicador de lo que es o no es bien recibido por la comunidad ya que la conformamos personas muy diversas, empezando por nuestra ubicación y continuando por la forma en la que participamos.

Entiendo que puede ser frustrante recibir un voto negativo porque a mí me pasa así como a otros que también han pasado por aquí con preguntas similares.

Si ya has hecho tu mejor esfuerzo por que tus publicaciones sean útiles y completas, se paciente, los votos positivos ya llegarán.

En cuanto a la pregunta específica que refieres, esta carece de una descripición de lo buscado e investigado como se sugiere en https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Además es ambigua, dice "he seguido el tutorial de un foro" sin ser claro de qué tutorial y foro habla.

Este tipo de "defectos" de las preguntas, salvo en el caso de que el autor haya provisto los datos necesarios en comentarios, no deberían ser corregidos por la comunidad, pues si el autor de la pregunta no dió los datos no hay forma que sepamos con certeza a que se refiere.

Luego están los criterios un tanto más complicados como lo es el caso de la utilidad de la pregunta y el de que sea de interés general.

Sobre cómo y dónde se pueden hacer ese tipo de preguntas, me parece que se responde en [Necesito ayuda para encontrar **algo** relacionado con programación ¿puedo pedir ayuda aquí?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3506/65)